# XSD extend restricted type

Tags: xsd

Can you have an allready restricted type and then derive from this type by extension and add elements that do not fit to a base type?

```
<xsd:complexType name="absHcontainerType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="e:urContentType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="e:absMcontainer" minOccurs="0"
                    maxOccurs="1" />
                <xsd:element ref="e:absHtitle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element ref="e:absMcontainer" />
                    <xsd:element ref="e:absHcontainer" />
                    <xsd:element ref="e:absContainer" />
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="e:typehcontainer" />
            <xsd:attributeGroup ref="e:anyattr" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And then derive this like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="absHcontainerType2">
  <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="absHcontainerType">
            <xs:sequence> 
               <xs:element name="xy" type="xs:string"/> 
               <xs:element name="xyz" type="xs:string"/> 
             </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>  
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't put back things that got restricted away, I wouldn't expect a problem.  Are you in fact getting an error when you try it?

Comment: Thank you for answer.
What I dont understand is this: OK you have the absHcontainerType type, which allows only absMcontainer,absHtitle,absHcontainer and absContainer elements. 
How come you can extend it with other elments? 
You can add a new type that is inherited from one of the types in its base restrictions. Therefore I would only be able to extend it with types inherited from: absMcontainer,absHtitle,absHcontainer and absContainer. No other. Or what is wrong in my thinking?

In example I have made an extension with string. This is not listed in base restrictions.